Calculating the number of terms required to approximate total sum within a specific error
I have the following infinite series. I am supposed to calculate the number of terms required to approximate the total sum of the series with an error of less than 0.01.
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^k\frac{1}{\ln(\ln(k+5))}}
$$
I know that for the given series (convergent and alternating), $\lvert R_n\rvert\le a_{n+1}$, and that for this particular problem, I need to find the smallest value of n that satisfies the conditions for $a_{n+1}\lt0.01$.
This is my work:
$$a_n=\frac{1}{ln(ln(n+5))}\text{ and }a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{ln(ln(n+6))}$$
$$a_{n+1}\lt0.01$$
$$\frac{1}{\ln(\ln(n+6)}\lt\frac{1}{100}$$
$$\ln(\ln(n+6))\gt100$$
$$\ln(n+6)>e^{100}$$
$$n+6>e^{e^{100}}$$
$$n>e^{e^{100}}-6$$
However, when I plug this number into my calculator to try and get a decimal or any sort of number, I get an error. Am I doing something wrong, or is there just no answer?

I suspect that your error is coming from the fact that $e^{e^{100}}$ is a preposterously large number. It has on the order of $10^{43}$ digits.

I thought that might be the case, but I wasn't one hundred percent sure, and I'm super new to the series, so I didn't know. Do you know if there is any way I can express my answer as $n\ge\text{something}$, or do I just leave it as is?
